# Issue returning values from function

Tags: c++, function

My program calculates the average score for each student. It outputs the numeric average and the letter grade. With these two functions, I am able to get the letter grade for each student just fine, **but I can't figure out how to obtain the total amount of each letter grade**. (please note that I'm not allowed to use structures, or arrays or vectors, etc. for this assignment :( )

```
#include <iostream>

string letterScore(double&);
int scoreCounter(string&);

using namespace std;

int main() {
    /* repeat for 5 students */
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        /* for simplicity, assume avgScore has already been calculated 
           and that function returned the average scores received for 
           each student: 90, 80, 70, 60, and 50 respectively */

        // pass the average score to figure out letter grades
        string letterscore = letterScore(avgScore);
    }

    return 0;
}

string letterScore(double& avgScore) {

    int As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Fs = 0;
    string letterscore;

    if (avgScore >= 90)
    {
        letterscore = "A";
        As = scoreCounter(letterscore);
    }
    else if (avgScore >= 80 && avgScore <= 89)
    {
        letterscore = "B";
        Bs = scoreCounter(letterscore);
    }
    else if (avgScore >= 70 && avgScore <= 79)
    {
        letterscore = "C";
        Cs = scoreCounter(letterscore);
    }
    else if (avgScore >= 60 && avgScore <= 69)
    {
        letterscore = "D";
        Ds = scoreCounter(letterscore);
    }
    else if (avgScore >= 50 && avgScore <= 59)
    {
        letterscore = "F";
        Fs = scoreCounter(letterscore);
    }

    return letterscore;
}

int scoreCounter(string& letterscore) {
    int counter = 0;

    if (letterscore == "A")
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else if (letterscore == "B")
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else if (letterscore == "C")
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else if (letterscore == "D")
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else if (letterscore == "F")
    {
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

I know the problem lies in the second function and how I am connecting the two. Right now, the output for As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Fs is 0 instead of 1 for each (assuming the average received of 90, 80, 70, 60, and 50 mentioned above). How can I get back in `main()` the total count for each letter grade? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know exactly what you are allowed to do or not to do.
Considering you cannot use arrays nor structures, you can solve your problem only with your `letterScore` function by passing your counters in parameters as reference :

```
string letterScore(double& avgScore, int& countA, int& countB, int& countC, [etc...]) {
    string letterscore;

    if (avgScore >= 90)
    {
        letterscore = "A";
        countA++; // here is the counter !
    }
    [etc...] // do the same for other blocks
```

and in your `main()` :

```
int countA = countB = [etc...] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        string letterscore = letterScore(avgScore, countA, countB, [etc...]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, you nailed it and it was that simple.